# Recommendations for table structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Hi I've got a small internal project I am working on. Currently it only serves my company, but I'd like to scale it so that it could serve multiple companies. The tables I have at the moment are `USERS` and `PROJECTS`. I want to start storing company specific information and relate it to the `USERS` table. For each user, I will have a new column that is the company they belong to.

Now I also need to store that companies templates in the database. The templates are stored as strings like this:

> "divider","events","freeform" etc.

Initially I was thinking each word should go in as a separate row, but as I write this I'm thinking perhaps I should store all templates in one entry separated by commas (as written above).

Bottom line, I'm new to database design and I have no idea how to best set this up. How many tables, what columns etc. For right now, my table structure looks like this:

```
PROJECTS
Project Number | Title | exacttarget_id | Author | Body | Date

USERS
Name | Email | Date Created | Password
```

Thanks in advance for any insights you can offer.

Comment: what is a company template and what is the relationship with the companies? Do you know about `1 to n` and `m to n` relationships in a relational database? If not, better start by some previous theoretical study, because even if someone will give you a solution you will not be able to understand it.

Comment: Elzo, if you mean tying common denominators (like company ID) then yes. If you meant something else, I'm not sure...

Comment: no. you should some reading, here is a start http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create 2 tables:

I would create one table for the different companies, lets call it `COMPANY`:

```
Company_id | Title | Logo | (Whatever other data you want)
```

I would also create one table for the settings listed above, lets call it `COMPANY_SETTINGS`:

```
Company_id | Key | Value
```

This gives you the flexibility in the future to add additional settings without compromising your existing code.  A simple query gets all the settings, regardless of how many your current version uses.

```
SELECT Key, Value FROM COMPANY_SETTINGS WHERE Company_id = :companyId
```

Te results can then be put into an associative array for easy use throughout the project.

Comment: This sounds perfect, exactly what I needed to know, just a good approach to organize my tables. Thanks!